# How can I create a user-friendly timestamp?

Tags: javascript, jquery, timestamp, momentjs

I am currently studying jQuery. What I am building now is called "twittler", which uses the jQuery and moment.js libraries.

I wrote the following code, but the time of twit creation is always "a few seconds ago". What is the problem?

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(() => {
      let index = 0, lastIndex = streams.home.length;
      let showTweet = () => {
        for (; index < lastIndex; index++) {
          let tweet = streams.home[index];
          let $tweet = $(
            `<div class="w3-card-4 w3-section">` +
            `<footer class="w3-container w3-opacity w3-right-align">` +
            `<h6 class="time" id="${tweet.created_at.getTime()}"></h6>` +
            `</footer>` +
            `</div>`
          );
          $tweet.prependTo($(".main-contents"));
        }
      };
      let lastIndexUpdate = () => {
        lastIndex = streams.home.length;
      };
      let timeUpdate = () => {
        $("h6.time").text(moment($("h6.time").attr("id"), "x").fromNow());
      };
      showTweet();
      setInterval(showTweet, 1000);
      setInterval(lastIndexUpdate, 1000);
      setInterval(timeUpdate, 1000);
    });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$("h6.time").attr("id")` will always get value of first matching selector only.

You need instance specific values

You can use [`text(function)`](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text-function) which will expose each instance in the callback

```
$("h6.time").text(function(){
    return moment(this.id, "x").fromNow();
});
```

Comment: I tried above, but output is `Invalid date`. anyway, thank you.

Comment: Is `tweet.created_at` a date object or still a string? What do you see in the dom when you inspect each ID?

Comment: `tweet.created_at` is a javascript date object. and `id="1510684802202"`

Comment: remove `.getTime()` and add a `+` in fron of `this.id` ==> `moment(+this.id, "x")`

Comment: still `Invalid date`.

Comment: Need to do some debugging inside the function. Create a demo with a few id's in jsfiddle or other sandbox

Comment: you didn't remove the `getTime()` and `this` is not the element inside arrow function. Arrow function has no `this` context